# Split file with both post and prefix

Tags: linux, filenames

How can I split file in Linux with number increment between post and prefix

For example

```
split -b 10M MyImages.tar.gz "MyImages*.tar.gz"
```

Result

```
MyImages01.tar.gz 
MyImages02.tar.gz
MyImages03.tar.gz
```

Comment: It's unclear whether you want to _split files_ or _rename files_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`split` can't do that, but you can use the perl `rename` utility (AKA `prename` or `perl-rename` or `file-rename`, depending on your distro) to rename the files immediately after splitting them.

e.g.

```
$ split -b 10M  --numeric-suffixes=1 MyImages.tar.gz XX-
$ rename -v 's/^XX-(\d+)$/MyImages$1.tar.gz/' XX-*
XX-01 renamed as MyImages01.tar.gz
XX-02 renamed as MyImages02.tar.gz
XX-03 renamed as MyImages03.tar.gz
XX-04 renamed as MyImages04.tar.gz
XX-05 renamed as MyImages05.tar.gz
XX-06 renamed as MyImages06.tar.gz
XX-07 renamed as MyImages07.tar.gz
XX-08 renamed as MyImages08.tar.gz
```

I'm using `XX-` as split's output filename prefix.  It doesn't really matter what it is, as long as it's not going to conflict with any existing files (and you use the same prefix for the `rename` script and filename args, of course).